# JavaScript Why my global array becomes empty? Console.log shows the correct value for a brief moment

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't figure out what is wrong here, I am sure it's something simple, but it is not easy to search for it, so I apologize if this has been answered already elsewhere.

**Situation:**

I declare a global array on top of my js file:

```
var question_ids = [];
```

The array gets some values:

```
$(".quiz-game-container .row").each(function(loop_index) {
    question_ids.push($(this).attr('id'));
}
```

Now I want to display a counter, which has the length of the array:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Sets the question info how many questions in total
    console.log(question_ids.length);
    $(".quiz-game-container .quiz-container .current-question-number").html("1/", question_ids.length);
});
```

**Problem**

The weird thing is, that I see the correct console.log output in the browser developer console (the length is 10), but it disappears after 1 second (probably when everything has been loaded) and there is no value, I get `1/` in html view.

Here is a live example of the disappearing console.log:
[my website](https://www.path-of-exile-builds.com/quiz)

Hit the refresh button `F5` and look at the console, the console.log output will show for a brief moment and then disappear.

**EDIT**

> Hit the refresh button `F5` and look at the console, the console.log output will show for a brief moment and then disappear.

This seems to be a browser issue. It works fine on FireFox.

Comment: There's some code missing. How does the array get filled with values?

Comment: @Pointy you have `question_ids.push($(this).attr('id'));`

Comment: $(".quiz-game-container .quiz-container .current-question-number").html("1/" **+** question_ids.length);

Comment: Try using `.text("1/" + question_ids.length)`

Comment: What do you mean it disappears? Which browser are you using? Usually the console gets cleared out when you refresh the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$.html only takes one parameter: http://api.jquery.com/html/

Change this:

```
.html("1/", question_ids.length);
```

To this:

```
.html("1/" + question_ids.length);
```

Comment: Thanks! But still why does the console.log output disappear?

Answer (score 1):

Replace this part

```
.html("1/", question_ids.length)
```

with

```
.html("1/" + question_ids.length)
```

Comment: Why would that help?

Comment: Because , is a separator for method arguments not a concatenation operator.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `("1/", question_ids.length)` 
with:
`("1/" + question_ids.length)`.
You want to join two variables not assign two values to the `.html()` function.

Comment: Thanks! But still why does the console.log output disappear?

Comment: It can't disappear from the console. What do you mean with that?

Comment: For me it didn't disappear. What browser do you use?

Comment: I use Chrome, on firefox the output stays. It seems it is a browser issue.

Comment: I've tested with with both Chrome and Firefox, and they both works.